# MSDN .Net Property Documentation Confusion - ItemStyle-Width

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, msdn

**Background**

I'm new to .NET and I am having trouble finding reference to certain properties/methods in the MSDN [.NET Framework Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) while researching certain classes. I come from a Java background and have become used to reading through Oracle's [Java API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) before using a new class. With the .NET documentation, however, I seem to be having trouble following the inheritance appropriately.

**Problem Details**

Specifically, I am in the process of tweaking a `Gridview` control and saw a few articles on Stack Overflow mentioning an `ItemStyle-Width` property on the `BoundField` class which may be of use to me. I play with my source code and sure enough I see this property available to me in the properties window but I want to know more about it before using it so I look up the documentation like so:

1. I look up the [Gridview documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) on MSDN
2. Under `Gridview` properties, I follow the [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property
3. Under `Columns` properties, I follow the [BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class field type
4. Under `BoundField`, I see a property call [ItemStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.itemstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which appears to be inherited from [DataControlField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
5. But now I run into a problem because neither of the above links list my `ItemStyle-Width` nor any other property that I see listed under `BoundField` in Visual Studio:

*BoundField Code:*
[image: My BoundField code]

*Properties List for BoundField:*

[image: Properties List for BoundField]

**Questions**

1) Where is this `ItemStyle-Width` property (or for that matter any of the `BoundField` properties) in the documentation? Am I not following the inheritance correctly?

2) What does the dash "-" represent in C#/.Net? I am seeing ItemStyle-[...] and ControlStyle-[...], etc... for certain properties in my properties list. Is this meant to be sub-properties of some sort? Why do some properties have a dash and others do not?

Answer (score 0):

1. Those aren't properties.  I'm not sure *where* they are coming from, but I know what they represent:  Properties of [TableItemStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableitemstyle_properties(v=vs.110).aspx).  That's the type of the `ItemStyle` property.  It's probably just some designer support to bring up commonly used properties to the top level so you can use the designer to configure them.
2. Nothing.  Again, this is probably some visual studio sorcery.

Side note, drop classic asp.net and get with MVC, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky until you get used to it.  I find working in the Source view of the designer to be far better for what you are trying to do as well as more intuitive.

Try this from the SourceView of your aspx page. a basic BoundField uses a self closing tag

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="yada" HeaderText="Yada" SortExpression="yada" />
```

until you apply a style say like the `Width` to the field, then you get something like this from the designer:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="yada" HeaderText="Yada" SortExpression="yada" >
    <Item Style Width="100px" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

However, you can also do this from the source view:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="yada" HeaderText="Yada" SortExpression="yada"
   ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
```

All of this is "Intellisensed" so as you start typing you will be prompted.

In fact if you manually convert the self closing tag `/>` to `>` and hit enter followed by an open angle `<`,  you'll be able to choose from the intellisense context menu of choices.